# Is there any way to populate data from Oracle Table to Active Directory?

Tags: oracle, plsql, active-directory, oracle11gr2

Is there any way to populate data from Oracle Table to Active Directory? We have a requirement to populate 1 column from 1 of the tables in an Oracle schema to Active Directory. We would like to automate this process.

Let me know if there is any solution for that?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Generally to talk with active directory you have to use `dbms_ldap` package. 
Start from setting up the connection to AD. And get to know how to querying AD. https://davegugg.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/querying-active-directory-through-oracle/.

Next step is updating records.
http://ermanarslan.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/plsql-dbmsldap-updating-active.html